# Vlookup not working if open excel sheet in invisible mode?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am retrieving data from another sheet using vlookup function, the source file opened in background mode, below is the code i used for hide the excel opening and screen update

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
app.Visible = False
```

But without above line vlookup working fine, when open in the invisible mode only vlookup function not working.

```
    partner = "C:\K\KDt\Con.xls"
    Set pf = app.Workbooks.Open(partner)
    Set ps = pf.Worksheets("Con")

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("KQC").Range("H4:H" & k) = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A4&""SP"",Contract_PARTNERS.xls!$H:$R,4,),"""")"
```

Comment: What does this mean: " i am get any result form vlookup."

Comment: @dbmitch  when i open excel in an invisible mode, vlookup reference not working. I am not get any result but when i open in view mode vlookup working fine

Comment: You need to show all of your code - otherwise needless obvious questions continue to be asked. Like ... have you set "Application.ScreenUpdating = True" before you set `app.visible = true`. Also where do you set app variable?

Comment: do you open the `Contract_Partners` workbook in a separate Excel Instance? If so, the other instance may not recognize the file as open.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Yes , this proeblem is source file opened in new instance since vlookup cant refernce, kindly advise me how to open excel in background  mode with already exists instance

Answer (score 0):

The issue is cause by how Excel treats links between workbook references. Your code is creating a link to a file that Excel expects is not open and is therefore incorrect. Even if it is not visible it is open.

To reference another workbook you do not have to have that file open at the same time.

Example formula when file is open:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,'1.csv'!$A:$I,9,0)
```

Same formula when file is closed

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,'C:\Users\nable\Documents\csvs\[1.csv]1'!$A:$I,9,0)
```

Excel should auto make the adjustment when the file is open/closed if the link was established at the time the formula was put in.